# How can I add css classes to a select list's options based on the value - using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

**Technology:**

asp.net MVC 5 .net framework + jQuery

**The case:**

I'm building a select list during runtime, where the data is fetched from the controller via ajax.
The data is returned to the ajax call as datatype `List<SelectListItem>`.
The select list is then built dynamically using jQuery. This is all well and it works.

**The problem:**

After appending all the options to the select list, I'm trying to add css classes to the options, based on their value. This is what I can't get to work.

I'm still fairly noob to debugging js in the browsers developer tools, but it seems to me, that the comparisons I make, doesn't act as I thought it would. Maybe the if/else comparisons is where I get it wrong!?

**The base HTML:**

```
<label for="EditBadge" class="form-label pt-00">Badge type</label>
<select class="form-control shadow mb-20" id="EditBadge" name="BadgeType">
</select>
```

**The jQuery ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/OrderSetting/GetOrderTypeData/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#EditOrderType').val(result.OrderType);
            $('#EditLeadTime').val(result.DeliveryDays);
            $('#orderTypeId').val(result.OrderSettingId);


            let data = result.BadgeTypes; // The List<SelectListItem>
            let options = $("#EditBadge"); // The empty select list

            options.find('option').remove(); // Clear any options from a previous operation

            // Populate the select list
            options.append($("<option />").val('Default').text('Select badge type ...'));
            $.each(data, function () {
                if (this.Value !== 'Default') {
                    if (this.Selected === true) {
                        options.append($("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Text).attr('selected', 'selected'));
                    } else {
                        options.append($("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Text));
                    }
                }
            });

            // FROM HERE ON THIS IS WHERE IT ALL FAILS
            // Get all the added options
            let newOptions = $('#EditBadge > option');

            // Iterate the options, add css based on the value property of the options element
            newOptions.each(function () {
                if (this.Value === 'Success') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-success');
                }
                else if (this.Value === 'Warning') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-warning');
                }
                else if (this.Value === 'Danger') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-danger');
                }
            });


        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('There was an error getting the entity data.');
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

By changing `this.Value` to `this.text` I now get the desired comparison. The debugger now throws an exception: *"this.addClass is not a function"*

So right now I'm working with this code:

```
let newOptions = $('#EditBadge > option');

            newOptions.each(function () {
                if (this.text === 'Success') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-success');
                }
                else if (this.text === 'Warning') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-warning');
                }
                else if (this.text === 'Danger') {
                    this.addClass('badge badge-pill badge-danger');
                }
            });
```

**Luckily for my case, the text and value property are the same. If someone has an idea why this.Value doesn't work, please leave a comment below. I'm still wondering how to access the value property.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling the exception led me to another SO answer, where the `this` keyword gets wrapped in the jQuery `$()` container. That does the trick.
The fully funtional code bit now reads:

```
let newOptions = $('#EditBadge > option');

            newOptions.each(function () {
                if (this.text === 'Success') {
                    $(this).addClass('badge badge-pill badge-success');
                }
                else if (this.text === 'Warning') {
                    $(this).addClass('badge badge-pill badge-warning');
                }
                else if (this.text === 'Danger') {
                    $(this).addClass('badge badge-pill badge-danger');
                }
```